# Bluebird Promise filter. Why Arrays?

Tags: javascript, bluebird, es6-promise

Looks like I missed something important with JS promises. Why Promise's `filter` method considers that promise content is Array/Iterable? Doesn't it looks like non-intuitive?

Here is Bluebird's filter signature:

```
Promise.filter(
  Iterable<any>|Promise<Iterable<any>> input,
  function(any item, int index, int length) filterer,
  [Object {concurrency: int=Infinity} options]
) -> Promise
```

There is at least one language which have Future/Promise in standard library - Scala, and it is tends to be quite logical that `Promise.filter` takes predicate and return `Resolved` promise if content satisfied provided predicate and `Rejected` with some `Error` if not:

```
Promise.filter(
  <any>|Promise<any> input, 
  function (any item) predicate
) -> Promise
```

This is how it can be used:

```
getUserFromDatabase()
  .filter( user => user.isEmailValid )
  .then( 
    user => { req.statusCode = 200; }  // user is okay
    err  => { req.statusCode = 404; }  // user is not okay
  )
```

Comment: `Promise.filter()` is modelled after [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), not after Scala.

Comment: @robertklep but how Promises are related to Arrays? Even if considering both as generic containers, it seems to be logical to apply filtering to value contained, not value-which-can-be-potentionally-an-array? Or am I wrong?

Comment: `Promise.filter()` is well described here http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html.  It's a function for operating on a collection of promises.  That's what it was built for.

Comment: @AlexPovar working with arrays of promises in relatively common in JS (hence the existence of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)). Filtering on a specific value can still be done, explicitly (by throwing if a value doesn't match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible intuitions what "filtering" could mean in the context of monads. Haskell makes this quite clear actually because it *does* have two distinct functions for this:

> ```
> mfilter :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
> ```
>
> Direct `MonadPlus` equivalent of `filter` applicable to any `MonadPlus`, for example `mfilter odd (Just 1) == Just 1`, `mfilter odd (Just 2) == Nothing`

By "direct equivalent" they mean `filter = (mfilter:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`), i.e. `mfilter` with `m` instantiated to `[]`, just like `map = fmap`.

> ```
> filterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
> ```
>
> This generalizes the list-based filter function.

It probably could even be generalised from lists to anything that is both `Foldable` and a `Monoid`, but let's keep it simple.

Both these functions could be applied to promises, which are an instance of `MonadPlus`. Scala chose the first one, Bluebird the second.

That's because `mfilter` can be quite trivially implemented with `.then(x => { if (predicate(x)) return x else throw … })` in JavaScript, and you even get to choose an error message or apply further transformations to `x` within the same callback. In contrast, an efficient `filterM` is not so easy to implement, but still quite useful and often needed, so Bluebird offers it as part of its utility belt for collections - including the *concurrency* option found in these methods.

Comment: As usual any question about any language can be replied with two oneliners in Haskell :)